# insecure content error in this app

Tags: php, ssl, https

[This link](https://www.facebook.com/Summit.HR.India/app_180318772033681) is giving me insecure content error on IE9. All resources are https .Why is this error? I ran it through firebug and whynopadlock.com and it shows all resources are https . what could be the reason for such a error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the resources are requested using `http` intead of `https`. Such as loading `Images`.

Answer (score 0):

"all are https" - but your browser is *explicitly reporting this is not the case*.

It's possible there is content being loaded via CSS / javascript over http. Try using iehttpheaders or wireshark to catpure the actual requests being made by the browser.

Comment: How did you get IE9 running on Linux? (wireshark available for lots of platforms including Linux and MSWindows)

Comment: ha ha.... i didnt use IE9 on linux but Win7.. BTW is there a way to run IE8 in linux(except IES4linux hack)

Comment: Even if you can get it runnning in emulation, you're never going to be sure what behaviours are due to MSIE, what ones are a result of the emulation layer and which ones are down to the native OS - I'd recommend using a virtual machine if a second box is not a practical solution.